# Django virtualenv layout

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I am very new to django. I just have a very basic question about project layout using virtualenv. When we create virtualenv and install all the dependencies-django etc, do I need to switch my directory to the virtualenv and then create a project there? Or do I need to create my project outside of virtualenv. I apologize if it is a very basic question.

Answer (score 22):

No, the directory where you create the virtual environment is completely separate and is not where you would go and create your django project.

In fact, you would usually put all your virtual environments in a separate directory; for me I put them in `$HOME/work/.envs` (note the `.`, this makes the directory hidden by default), so then my workflow becomes:

```
$ virtualenv $HOME/work/.envs/new_env
$ source $HOME/work/.envs/new_env/bin/activate
(new_env)$ pip install django
(new_env)$ cd ~/projects
(new_env)/projects$ django-admin.py startproject atestproj
```

So you see, you don't actually do anything with the virtual environment directory; it is completely managed by `virtualenv` and `pip`.

The [`virtualenvwrapper` project](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) makes this easier by managing your virtual environments in a central location.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have a question. Suppose I have django 1.4 installed in the root directory of my computer. Then I install django 1.5 in the virtualenv. Then I create django project outside of virtualenv- say on the desktop. Which django version will my project use? 1.4 or 1.5?

Comment: If you didn't activate the virtual environment, it will use 1.4, if you activated the virtual environment, then it doesn't matter where you are in the filesystem, it will use 1.5

Comment: You may specify which version to use explicitly (i.e.: `pip install django==1.4`) This is best practice, as later on you can `pip freeze` and create a requirements.txt, which you may then `pip install` on other machines, preserving version dependancies your project may have.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid That makes sense now. Why would you hide your virtualenv directory though? I mean in your comment you said you usually keep the virtualenv directory hidden.

Comment: Its just a personal preference; the environment directories are not someplace I want to accidentally make modifications or delete, so I keep them in a hidden directory; but since I started using virtualenvwrapper in my workflow, I use it to manage (including deleting) my environments.

Answer (score 2):

Directory structure for use with virtualenv should be as follows:

```
|-- project_name
    |-- django
        |-- project_name

|-- virtualenv
    |-- project_name
        |-- bin
```

This of course is not the definitive answer to how your project directory structure should be laid out—it has however worked for me, and others I know, over the years.

I highly recommend "twoscoops's" django project directory structure and tutorial for beginners:
https://github.com/twoscoops/django-twoscoops-project

I also recommend virtualenvwrapper, to make managing virtual environments easier:
http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 1):

This goes to the very heart of how you use virtualenv: cd to the virtualenv directory, then activate it (or the other way around - it doesn't really matter). The usual way to do this on linux (or cygwin) is to source `./bin/activate/` from inside the virtualenv.

At that point, if you use `pip` or `python` they will be local to that virtualenv. You should only perform your installations, and run your stuff *after* activating the virtualenv.

So, to answer your question: switch and activate *before* you start to install or do anything. Do everything inside the virtualenv, with it activated.

Comment: I appreciate your response. However, I have seen a youtube video where they first activate it and then change the directory. Is there a preferred way for this?

Comment: @hansaraj it doesn't matter whether you switch into the directory first. You must activate before you do anything, and it is generally more convenient to be inside the directory to do things in it. If you want to not cd into it, that's fine, but it will make things less convenient.