# How to install django for python 3.3

Tags: python, django, macos

I had python 2.6.1 because it was old I decide to install python 3.3.2 but, when I type "python" in my mac it prints it is version 2.6.1 and when I type python3 it shows that this is 3.3.2. I installed django 1.6 but when I check, understand that it is installed for old version of python (python 2.6.1). I want to instal it for my python 3.3.2 what should I do? any way to uninstall python 2.6.1 and when I enter python in terminal it's version be 3.3.2? I have mac os 10.6.8

Comment: Use virtualenv. Refer to this post for further details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17837723/django-virtualenv-layout

Comment: I think [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12566853/1265154) is a little bit more correct.

Comment: I don't think OP wants to keep the old version, so those links might not be relevent...

Comment: yes, I really don't need to keep old version of python just want to replace new with old and set python3 as default version, I mean when I type python in terminal python 3.3.2 will be print

Comment: @sandra and no issues on osx caused by py 2.6 absence? I have harder times on ubuntu.

Comment: I didn't uninstall python 2.6 to know it cause any issue or not but I want to replace these 2 versions.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You could use `pip` to manage the package for you. If `pip` is not installed. 
use

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

to install it. Then

```
pip3 install django
```

would install `django` for your python3.

Answer (score 8):

Use `python3` to call python version 3 on the command line.

For projects you can use virtual environments:

```
$ python # this will be version 2
$ python3 -m venv myenv
$ source myenv/bin/activate
$ python # this will be version 3
```

where `myenv` will be the folder that hosts the libraries and binaries for that virtual environment. It will automcatically use the python version that was used to initialize this venv - in this case `python3`. This has the effect that once you activate the venv you can use `python` there and it will be version 3.

Answer (score 1):

to setup django in pyton3

1. sudo apt-get install python3-pip
2. sudo pip3 install virtualenv
3. virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.**X** venv
4. source venv/bin/activate

congrats you have setup python3 django and now have many packages to work with

Note: **X** stands for the version of python

Answer (score 0):

To install **django for python3**, you need to use **pip3** instead of **pip**.

python defaults to python2.
pip defaults to pip for python2.
So, when you install pip using whatever package manager you have, you are essentially installing pip for python2.

**To remove Python2:** `$sudo apt remove python`

**To install pip for python3:** 
`$sudo apt install python3-pip`

To install pip for python2:
`$sudo apt install python-pip`

**Note:** I am using **apt** package manager. You should use the package manager for your OS.